# How to close thread and start thread appropriate ways?

Tags: python

I need to **run** and **close** thread with **input**. Here, it uses input function to handle input. If input is **start**. then, run recv method as thread else input is **close** set second argument to False. False value to indicate loop inside recv to stop. But, My console keep open. It should close console. Cause it end of loop.

```
class Device():
    def open(self, port, baudrate):
        try:
            return serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
        except SerialException as e:
            error = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(e))

            self.__error['port'] = error[0]
            self.__error['description'] = error[1]

            return None

    def __state(self, open):
        if open is None:
            if self.__error['description'] == 'Access is denied.':
                return True
            elif self.__error['description'] == 'Port is already open.':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True

    def write(self, device, command):
        if self.__state(device):
                device.write(command.encode('UTF-8') + b'\r')
        else:
            print(self.__error['port'] + ' ' + self.__error['description'])

    def recv(self, device, open = True):
        while open:    
            if self.__state(device):
                buffer = device.readline()

                print(buffer)

                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print(device[0] + ' ' + device[1])

                time.sleep(1)

device = Device()

serial = device.open('COM12', 9600)

while True:
    command = input('Enter a command: ')
    if command == 'start':
        t = threading.Thread(target=device.recv, args=(serial,))
        t.start()
    elif command == 'close':
        device.recv(serial, False)
    elif command == 'imei':
        device.write(serial, 'AT+CGSN')
```

Comment: I think the formatting on your code is messed up....  as it is being displayed, you have a class with no body, and then a bunch of functions that probably belong as members of that class, but due to the indent level will not be interpreted that way. Try enclosing your entire code block in triple-backticks (before and after).

Comment: @Z4-tier what do you means `triple-backsticks`? I edit more code. what the class can do. I add `write` method and conditional in bottom command. If input is `imei`. it print out imei device. But, i try it to close. but the thread keep open. Cause after i typed close. It still print out imei number when i type imei.

Comment: I edited the post to fix the indent levels, I think you should be able to approve the edit if what I did looks correct.

Comment: @Z4-tier Okay, i adds more descriptive information i change error list from index access to associative like `__error['port']` and `__error['description']`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, you are trying to do this:

1. When you begin the program and issue the `start` command, a new thread (Thread-2) begins executing in the `recv()` method of the `device` object
2. The main thread (Thread-1) continues in the event loop and presents another input prompt. At the same time, Thread-2 is looping forever inside of `recv()`
3. In Thread-1, you then issue the `close` command with the intention that it should disrupt Thread-2, causing it to break out of the loop and stop writing output to the terminal.

If that is correct, then the problem is in **step 3**: When Thread-1 makes the call `device.recv(serial, False)`, it has no impact on the execution of Thread-2. That is because, when a thread is created and the `start` method is called:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=my_func)
t.start()
```

the new thread will begin executing `my_func`, but it will do so *with it's own call stack, instruction pointer, and registers.*  Later, when Thread-1 calls `device.recv()`, it will result in a stack frame being pushed onto the call stack of Thread-1. That call is completely separate from the one that is already running in Thread-2.

Threads share many resources: Text, Data and BSS memory segments; open file descriptors; and signals (plus some other resources as well). Call stacks are *not* shared<sup>1</sup>.

If you need to communicate between threads, the `threading` library provides several options that can help. One such option is `threading.Event`, which can be used to communicate the occurrence of some event between threads. You could use it like this:

```
term_event = threading.Event()

class Device:
    def recv(self, device):
        while not term_event.isSet():
            if self.__state(device):
                buffer = device.readline()
                print(buffer)
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print(device[0] + ' ' + device[1])
                time.sleep(1)
        term_event.clear()
```

This creates an `event` object that *is* shared by all of the threads in the process. It can be used by Thread-1 as a way to tell Thread-2 when to exit. Then, you need to change the event loop like this:

```
while True:
    command = input('Enter a command: ')
    if command == 'start':
        t = threading.Thread(target=device.recv, args=(serial,))
        t.start()
    elif command == 'close':
        term_event.set()
    elif command == 'imei':
        device.write(serial, 'AT+CGSN')
```

Instead of calling the `recv` method a second time, juist `set` the shared `event` object, which Thread-2 interprets as a signal to exit. Before exiting, Thread-2 calls `term_event.clear()`, so a new thread can be started later on.

---

<sub>1: Since the threads are part of the same process, they actually occupy the same memory space as allocated by the kernel. As a consequence, each thread's private stack is  (in theory) accessible by any other thread in that program.</sub>

Comment: It loop infinite. The console keep open. then, It can't type anything again. It should can type again to start or close.

Comment: so you want the `while True` loop to continue executing after the new thread terminates?